# Is this a subjective complement or an adverbial clause of comparison?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, parsing

> He is as clever as I am.

Is **'As clever as I am'** an adverbial clause of comparison functioning as an adverbial adjunct, or is it the subjective complement to the verb 'is'? If the last case is true, what would be its category?

Because I know that in the sentence 'He is clever' clever is an adjective functioning as subjective complement, because the verb 'to be' always takes subjective complement. That's why I think that 'as clever as I am' is a subjective complement, but I read in a grammar book that it is actually an adverbial clause of comparison.

And if it is actually an adverbial clause of comparison, it cannot function as subjective complement, because adverbial clauses always function as adverbial adjunct, so I'm really lost here.

Comment: You are right: "as clever as I am" is an adjective phrase serving as subjective complement of "is". It's "I am" that is the comparative clause serving as comp of the second "as". The comparative clause is obligatorily reduced, as most comparative clauses are. We understand that *"He is as clever as I am clever", which of course is ungrammatical, so we drop the "clever". (Note that you could also say "He is as clever as me").

Comment: This is one of these grammar questions to which the proper response is "who cares?"  Do you know what it means?  Yes? Good, move on.

Answer (score 0):

As can be used as 1) preposition 2) conjunction 3)adverb
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as

"As + adjective + as" is used as a comparative adjective.
"As+ adverb + as" is used as a comparative adverb.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as

1. We could write sentences like "He is **as clever as**[comparative adjective] John[noun]"
2. The world’s biggest bull is **as big as**[comparative adjective] a small elephant  [noun phrase].

As we can see, we have a noun, or noun phrase coming after the adjective.

Now, moving on to your example: "He is as clever as I am."

We can interpret the sentence as:
He is[link verb] as[adverb] clever[adjective] as[conjunction] I am.

Another example of this type: You’re as pretty as I remember.

The linking verb normally take a nominative or predicative word. But we do have other cases as well.

Examples: "He is in the garden." Here, the prepositional phrase "in the garden' serves as an adverb. (answers where is he)

He is upstairs ( some sources take upstairs as adverb, while some take it as a prepositional phrase meaning 'up the stairs')

Hope that helps!